# Error while using usedrange.find

Tags: vba, excel

My workbook consists of two worksheets (sheet 1 and sheet 2)

I want to look for the ID in sheet 1 in column J, and Need to look for its corresponding date in sheet 2 , which is in column G.

I want that date to be printed in column W of sheet 1.

The Problem is, in a few cases I am getting my comment section, which is in column L of sheet 2 , instead of date.

The column G in sheet 2 is completely filled.

Could anyone, suggest, what is the Problem with my code or execution. I just want the date to be printed, if not, then I don't Need anything to be printed.

```
Sub lookup()

Dim totalrows As Long
Dim totalcolumn As Long
Dim rng As range
Dim rng1 As range
Dim i As Long

totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To totalrows

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 7).Value)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

Cells(i, 23).Value = rng.Value

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put there another `Sheets("Sheet2")` to get the correct reference:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 7).Value)
```

Try to work with the `With...End With` statements. Then you can use a Point (".") to refer to the sheets you set in the with Statements.

After some comments I think this one's what you Need:

```
Sub lookup()
    Dim totalrows As Long
    Dim totalcolumn As Long
    Dim rng As String
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        totalrows = .Range(.Cells(1, 10), .Cells(1, 10).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        For i = 2 To totalrows
            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                rng = .UsedRange.Find(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value).Offset(0, -3).Value
            End With

            If rng <> "" Then
                .Cells(i, 23).Value = rng
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This code finds the ID from cell J2 in Sheet2. After that, it saves the value of the cell 3 columns before (J - 3 columns is column G). This one is the date you want to write into your cell W2. And thats for all rows until column J is empty.
Is that the functionallity you want to have?

Comment: It dint work,  still it  is copying the other row values

Comment: ok, i don't get your Problem. You want to look for a string, which is in sheet1, to get a date from sheet2? Your code does the following:
it selects sheet1 (not necessary), it sets the variable rng to the range of the first cell containing the value of Range(G1) on sheet1. Then you take that range objects value and type that into sheet1's range(W1). 

Where is your ID you're looking for?

Comment: ya my code, Looks for  string, and gets the date from sheet 2 .

Comment: while getting the date, in somecases it takes the comment section which is in column l

Comment: see, thats your Problem, you want to get the value of something and you save the whole object to a variable. Simply save the Value to your variable without the set-element:

Sub lookup()

Dim totalrows As Long
Dim totalcolumn As Long
Dim rng As String
Dim rng1 As range
Dim i As Long

totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To totalrows

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value).Value

If rng <> "" Then

Cells(i, 23).Value = rng
End If

Next i

End Sub

Something like that

Comment: How do i do it. I am sorry to ask directly, I have just started practicing VBA